# How to Know The Number of Alive Nodes in NS2?

Tags: networking, ns2

I am working on the NS2 simulator and I got a trace file, so I need to know Network lifetime (the number of alive nodes with simulation time).

My Questions Are:

Is there such a way to do this?

What is the parameter that holds this value (number of alive nodes)?

Comment: What's "the NS2 simulator"? Are you using Ubuntu? Which? Do you know the format of the "trace file"?

Comment: Google, ns2 "alive nodes" : Example hit https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk02mCqGsiNVC00asDtG5aC5-D5CRSA:1589102065631&source=univ&tbm=isch&q=ns2+%22alive+nodes%22&hl=all&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwicrYjB-qjpAhWvwqYKHT81AzoQsAR6BAgDEAE&biw=1155&bih=590

Comment: Simulation example, kartiksd-leach.tcl : Writes "The number of alive nodes after XX round=yy" and plots `alivenodes vs time` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Iw_FYntMWh7oy7g7_gbIZ-caPQJBIztR/view?usp=sharing .... ns2 https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ns-users

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks for your help